# Image before text in one div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to put image (css content property) before text inside div in my case?

JavaScript inserts different messages into the element with msgBox. **And unfortunatelly I cannot touch JS.**
Also text must be in the center (in the middle of the picture).

Requirements:

1. Message text is in the center
2. Between image and text strongly 10-20px
3. Div must not contain other elements
4. **Text and icon should be centered.**

```js
document.getElementById("msgBox")
  .innerHTML = "Here can be any text any long";
```

```css
#msgBox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="msgBox">(icon) text</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `height` and `verticle align:middle` css of image and put image before text.
Here is the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/a4utqvh1/2/

Answer (score 3):

You could try it with css `:before`:

```
#msgBox:before{
    content: url('path/to/your.png');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a4utqvh1/1/

Comment: I've updated the question. Unfortunatelly this solution violates 4 requirement. I think my problem has no solution (

Comment: @dmitmedv which ones? text is centered, for the margin just add `margin-right:15px`, div doesn't contain other element (actually it does but not in the DOM), and text and icon are centered (kinda redundant with first req)

Comment: @Kaiido i'm about 4 item. Now text and image are on the one line. Their centers line must be match. Is it possible?

Comment: My main problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dmitmedv/a4utqvh1/15/ text and image are on one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:before` in css to add your icon as a background image, so even if you change the content of your `div` in JS, the icon will still be there.

```
#msgBox:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px; // width of your image
    height: 10px; // height of your image
    background: url('img.jpg'); // path to your image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/a4utqvh1/3/

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.wrapper img,
#msgbox {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/2015/24x24_free_application/24/error.png" />
  <div id="msgBox">(icon) text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle using image as a background image

msgBox {

```
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
background: url(http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/2015/24x24_free_application/24/error.png) no-repeat 5px center;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/a4utqvh1/4/ will this work

Comment: it's good variant, but requirement 2 from my updated question is broken (

Comment: Try using text-indent property

Comment: Please update your answer with a stacksnippet. Your link is dead

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background-image-Attribute form a div-Element.

```
#msgBox {
  ...
  background-image: url('http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/2015/24x24_free_application/24/error.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: center;
  ...
}
```

A Sample with nice padding:
http://jsfiddle.net/bronni/a4utqvh1/7/

Comment: Please update your answer with a stacksnippet. Your link is dead

Answer (score 0):

may this will work, put image tag in innerHTML text

```js
document.getElementById("msgBox").innerHTML = "<img src='http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/2015/24x24_free_application/24/error.png'/> <span>Here can be any text any long</span>";
```

```css
#msgBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="msgBox">(icon) text</div>
```